# C# где хранится массив строк

Tags: c#

Есть простое приложение которое вставляет одну и ту же строку во все элементы массива:

```
        Stopwatch sw = new Stopwatch();
        sw.Start();

        string str = "This is test string";
        int maxInt = 14344390;

        string[] strArr = new string[maxInt];

        for (int i =0; i < maxInt; i++)
        {
            strArr[i] = str;
        }

        sw.Stop();

        Console.WriteLine($"Elapsed: {sw.ElapsedMilliseconds}");
        Console.WriteLine("Done");
        Console.ReadKey();
```

при этом по данным Visual Studio приложение занимает в памяти 69 мб. По данным стандартного монитора ресурсов приложение также в памяти занимает примерно столько же места и то же самое показывает RAMMap. Ок, если обратимся к теории, то строка в c# хранится в utf-16, то есть 2 байта. 20 символов по 2 байта умножим на 14344390 строк, получим 573 775 600 байта. и это только сами строки без доп. данных необходимых для хранения. если считать доп данные, то это ещё по 14 байт на строку(SyncBlockIndex(4 байта)+указатель типа(4 байта)+длина строки в int(4 байта)+null символ конца строки(2 байта)). Итого получается 774 597 060 байт. доп
Вопрос к знатокам. Где все эти данные со строками размещаются? Если эти данные не отображаются в Visual Studio, то посоветуйте инструмент который показывал истинное потребление памяти.

Comment: Строка это ссылочный тип данных

Comment: да, тупая ошибка, стоило к каждой строке прибавить i сразу всё стало на свои места

Answer (score 1, accepted):

У вас же не создаются новые строки, а используется ссылка на одну и ту же строку, заданную константно ещё при компиляции, так что вы тратите место только на ссылки.